# How to create dialog with percentage height in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to create a `p:dialog` component in primefaces with the size given in percents:

```
<p:dialog header="Dialog" widgetVar="dlg" width="70%" height="70%">
  Some content
</p:dialog>
```

The code above creates a component with the right width value. However height of the dialog is set to some very minimum value (definitely not 70%).

My question is: how can I set percentage height to the dialog?

I did some research and found in primefaces code that `height` value is explicitly [set to 'auto'](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/dialog/dialog.js?r=7056#34) and height attribute is [assigned to content div](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/dialog/dialog.js?r=7056#37). This explains why my code doesn't work, but what can I do to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to do it using javascript. The component definition should be modified:

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Dialog" widgetVar="dlg" width="70%" height="100%">
  Some content
</p:dialog>
```

In this way content will fill the dialog completely. And now following javascipt code should be called:

```
var htmlTag = document.getElementById('dialog');
htmlTag.style.height = Math.floor(window.innerHeight*0.7)+"px";
```

This will resize a dialog height to 70% of the window height.

Comment: from where and how did you call this JavaScript code? I have the same problem now.

Comment: I don't remember where I did it. I expect I put it in onShow attribute or something similar

Comment: I confirm. It's working putting the script in the onShow attribute.
Pay attention to the id of the element.
Thank you, gawi

Answer (score 1):

Hight and Width might be given in pixcels, try using style

```
<p:dialog ... style="width:70% !important; height:70% !important;">
   Some content
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: I've already tried it, you can resize the dialog this way, but the content doesn't fit properly to the dialog.